# Starting UserControl Storyboard from code behind another UserControl

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to access UserControl (Parent) Storyboard from a code behind of another UserControl (Child). I have a UserControl (Parent User Control) that contains another UserControl (Child User Control). Parent User Control have a Storyboard that is being utilized by the Parent User Control, and now, I would like to start playing that Storyboard from a code behind of Child User Control. Is there a way to achieve that. Here is sample code:

Parent User Control:

```html
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sbShowEditLetter">
            <DoubleAnimation 
           Storyboard.TargetName="grdOptions"
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" 
           From="0" To="10" 
           Duration="0:0:5">
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="grdOptions"
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" 
               From="0" To="420" 
               Duration="0">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

```html
                        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add ...">
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sbShowEditLetter}">
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
```

Child User Control:

```html
    private void dgLetters_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement originalSender = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if (originalSender != null)
        {
            var row = originalSender.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
            if (row != null)
            {

                //access Parent User Control Storyboard
                Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("sbShowEditLetter") as Storyboard;
                sb.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, here is the updated code behind:

```html
        private void dgLetters_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement originalSender = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (originalSender != null)
            {
                var row = originalSender.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
                if (row != null)
                {

                    DependencyObject ucParent = this.Parent;

                    while (!(ucParent is UserControl))
                    {
                        ucParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(ucParent);
                    }

                    MainWindow2 parentUserControl = (MainWindow2) ucParent;
                    parentUserControl.vm.ExecuteEdit();

                    Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("sbShowEditLetter") as Storyboard;
                    sb.Begin();
                }
            }
        }
```